# How to modify the list form in SharePoint 2013 designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to add new column to my list form ,I want to display this new field on middle of form, but it currently added last of my page.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need SharePoint Designer to do that. Just go to your list settings, and then go down to where the columns are. You will have a link called "Column Ordering".

[image]

Comment: There is no column ordering option other three option there but this not.

Comment: Hey Mike there is no link for column ordering

Comment: You need to go Advanced Settings and set No Allow management of content types?  then you get this option.

Answer (score 0):

Open the NewForm.aspx in the Designer. Search your column name. It will be there in the form of xml under `<tr></tr>` tag. Cut that `<tr></tr>` tag( the one containing a column whose position needs to be modified) and paste it below the  tag of other column which is appearing in the middle of your form. Save It.

Note: There is two `<tr></tr>` tag for each column. so both needs to be adjusted.

Comment: the user will need to add a new form in order to see the columns. You shouldn't edit the default "NewForm.aspx". If the user has a custom form already as the default, this will work perfectly.

Comment: Yes i am not see there column name on my NewForm.aspx page

Comment: yeah I miss that.. Create a custom new form by clicking on the New Form tab in the list in SharePoint Designer and make it as default. this new form will have all the columns